# How to test possible interactions in GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction

I'm coding an GLM (with a tweedie distribution, log link) with 24 variables, 6 of which are binary dummy variables, 3 are categorical and the rest continuous.  Is there a way to test for all possible interactions to find interactions that are statistically significant, not necessarily in terms of p-values but to a way that lends more accuracy to the model?

Comment: do you mean stepwise model selection?

Comment: No I don’t mean stepwise. I mean for example, I have age, marital status, motorcycle type, value of bike and I want to predict propensity of having a claim. Is there a way to test all possible interactions by way of some sort of test or method?